# How to modify the demo of vue.js 1.0 to apply to vue.js 2.0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

demo：

using vue `1.0`,it works : https://jsfiddle.net/0qudfr48/1/

using vue `2.0`,it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/0qudfr48/

The code of the two demos are the same,only the vesions of vue.js are different.

How to modify the demo to apply to vue.js 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Two breaking changes exist for v2.

1. v-for
   https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-for-Argument-Order-for-Arrays-changed
2. vm.$set
   https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#vm-set-changed

Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/0qudfr48/9/

```
v-for="(item, index) in items"
...
Vue.set(vm, 'items', mysqlData.map((item) => {
...
```